# How to change Paramiko SSH Banner/version ?

Tags: python, ssh, server, paramiko, banner

I am developing a custom SSH server and I am looking to change Paramiko (http://www.paramiko.org/) SSH Banner/version.

Here is the nmap output:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     Paramiko Python sshd 2.1.1 (protocol 2.0)
```

I would like to change it to :

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     My sshd 1.0 (protocol 2.0)
```

Here is the code I am using to create my SSH server : https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/demo_simple.py

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The banner used by the client/server [comes from](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/cd323c6cdaa8898444e2d497909f93751799f60e/paramiko/transport.py#L1742) the [`local_version`](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/cd323c6cdaa8898444e2d497909f93751799f60e/paramiko/transport.py#L327) attribute of the `Transport` class, so if you change it before you call `start_server()` or `start_client()` on the transport then it should work, e.g:

```
transport.local_version = 'SSH-2.0-My sshd 1.0'
transport.start_server(...)
```

Note that what nmap reports depends on which probe in [nmap-service-probes](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/a134cc916e46f60d52d8847e3f03d70011207622/nmap-service-probes) is triggered, so your output in nmap might be different from what you expect. The line that matches for paramiko would be:

```
match ssh m|^SSH-([\d.]+)-paramiko_([\w._-]+)\r?\n| p/Paramiko Python sshd/ v/$2/ i/protocol $1/
```